# Create ordered columns in postgres with Doctrine

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I'm converting a project to `Doctrine 2.4` and the used database there is PostgreSQL. 
I was wondering if it's possible to tell `Doctrine` to create the columns of the table(entity) in a particular order?

The table I'm currently converting has a lot of columns and some of them are relations to other tables. When the table is created, the first columns would be the `primary keys`, followed by `foreign keys` and at the end - everything else.

Here is an example code:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="receipts")
 */
class Receipt {


    /**
     * @var
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Column(name="receipt_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $receipt_id;

    /**
     * @var
     * @Column(name="created_date", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $created_date;

    /**
     * @var
     * @Column(name="updated_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updated_date;


    /**
     * @var
     * @Column(name="invoice_number", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $invoice_number;

    /**
     * @var
     * @Column(name="invoice_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $invoice_date;

    /**
     * @var
     * @Column(name="invoice_link", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $invoice_link;

    /**
     * @var
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="models\Receipts\Invoice\Type")
     * @JoinColumn(name="invoice_type_id", referencedColumnName="invoice_type_id")
     */
    private $invoiceType;

    /**
     * @var
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="models\Payments\Method")
     * @JoinColumn(name="invoice_payment_method_id", referencedColumnName="payment_method_id")
     */
    private $invoicePaymentMethod;

    /**
     * @var
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="models\Payments\Type")
     * @JoinColumn(name="invoice_payment_type_id", referencedColumnName="payment_type_id")
     */
    private $invoicePaymentType;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->created_date = new \Date_Time();
        $this->updated_date = new \Date_Time();
    }

?>
```

The code above will look like this in `PHPPgAdmin`:
[image]

And this is how I would like the columns to appear:
[image]

Of course, everything is working fine. It's just the people working on the project with me (including I) are used to seeing the tables & columns ordered in a concrete way so that we could find things fast and easy. Hopefully there is a Doctrine ninja here that could help me with this. I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried YAML/XML mapping ? Maybe the field order is keeped.

Comment: I haven't thought about that - I'll have to try, although we would rather have the entities in PHP format so we could use them as objects in the project. Usually when using php entities, Doctrine preserves the order, but for some reason it doesn't do that in this example...